# Integrate Firebase cloud Messaging in Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project in Android which I developed with eclipse. I want to add push notification to my project.

New solution is Firebase Cloud Messaging and I want to use it. But all documents and samples are coded with Android Studio, but I could not move to Android Studio because of some dependencies.

I could not solve this problem in eclipse. Is there any way to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Eclipse project?

Comment: Are you using gradle to build your project in eclipse?

Comment: No I am not using gradle. How can I use it, I dont know...

Comment: There is a gradle plugin for eclipse but I am not familiar with it. If possible I'd try Android Studio since eclipse support by the Android team has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. In the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), its stated that:

> To write your Firebase Cloud Messaging Android client app, use the FirebaseMessaging API and **Android Studio 1.4 or higher with Gradle**.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested this and encourage anyone who comes across this answer to save themselves countless hours and move on to Android Studio.

## Step 1

Download the latest Google Play services library (at least v9.0.0) from the Android SDK Manager and import it to your Eclipse project.

## Step 2

Since you can't use `google-services` gradle plugin you have to setup Firebase yourself. In your custom `Application.onCreate` call:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    // Setup here.
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
```

Setup options: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder

You will need to set at least the API key, application ID and GCM sender ID all of which you can find in your Firebase / Google Dev Console.

## Step 3

Update your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <!-- FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
         no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

The values were taken from Play services library v9.6.1. Replace `${applicationId}` with your app ID.

**Rant:** Do you want to know why we use Android Studio and Gradle? Because then we don't have to do any of this **** and it updates automatically with each new version of the library.

## Step 4

Update your proguard rules:

```
# Proguard flags for consumers of the Google Play services SDK
# https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable classes & their creators to not get renamed, as they are
# found via reflection.
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final *** CREATOR;
}

# Keep the classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keep @interface android.support.annotation.Keep
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Keep Dynamite API entry points
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi
-keep @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi public class * {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}

# Needed when building against pre-Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

# Needed when building against Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.app.Notification

# Needed for isDeviceProtectedStorage when building against a pre-Nougat SDK.
-dontwarn android.content.Context
```

## Step 5

Go on with your tutorial for Android Studio and Gradle at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client.